# Get generics parameter for new instance

Tags: java, generics

I need to make an instance of generic class. Do not know what to use as parameter.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Class type = someMethod(); //It could return String.class, Integer.class, MyClass.class etc
        //Now I need to make a instance of something using generic parameter. I use List as example here.
        List<type)> list = new ArrayList<>(); //Does not work, obvioulsy since it looks weird.
       //But what does work?
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't use Generics like that. Generics are a compile-time tool but your code will resolve the class only at runtime.

Comment: `List<T>` is actually list of `Object`s due to generic erasure, you cannot parameterize  it on runtime. Most you can do is checking if instance if of given class, for example, by `type.isAccessibleFrom(instance.getClass())`

Comment: @Thomas I see. Compile time tool, never thought of it. Good to know. I'll find another way.

Answer (score 0):

You can make compiler ensure compile-type (not runtime) safety for you by passing desired class of `List` elements:

```
public static <T> List<T> makeList(@SuppressWarnings("UnusedParameters") Class<T> elClass) {
    return new ArrayList<>();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<String> strings = makeList(String.class);
    List<Integer> ints = makeList(Integer.class);
}
```